# Factorial ANOVA with missing cell

Tags: r, anova, missing-data, lm, two-way

I would like to run a two-way ANOVA with interaction between the two factors. I did an experiment with two treatments: Treatment 1 has four levels (A,B,C,D) and treatment 2 has three levels (I, P,F). Each level of treatment 2 is represented in (almost) each level from treatment 1, except of A where there are only two levels of treatment 2, as shown here:

[image]

I fitted a linear model in R using the function lm and subsequently ran an ANOVA using the Anova function from the car package:

```
> model <- lm(data=data, response ~ treat1*treat2)
> Anova(model)
```

I got a note that my model has aliased coefficients and that the sums of squares were computed by model comparisons, but the analysis ran perfectly. However, I´m wondering whether it is ok to carry out this analysis here due to the incomplete design? As far as I now, for a full factorial ANOVA there has to be a complete design with at least one observation in each cell, but perhaps fitting a linear model using lm can get around this problem? Any suggestions and/or references would be higly appreciated.